# Looping a transition in Unity UI Toolkit using USS styles

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

Recently Unity release their new [UI Toolkit](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.2/Documentation/Manual/UIElements.html), which has been great so far. I have a countdown element in my document, and I am planning on **animating it to pulse** once the number reaches a threshold.

Here is the current transition:

[image]

How can I **loop the animation endlessly**?

Current USS code is below. I have tried similar css properties such as `animation-iteration-count: infinite;` but no luck so far, and the documentation doesn't appear complete yet.

```css
#timer-countdown:hover {
    scale: 1.2 1.1;
    color: rgba(255, 170, 170, 255);
    transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out-cubic;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The advice I've seen from Unity in the forums and other places is to control animations and other behaviours in C# where the uss isn't developed enough.

[A gif showing a rotating circle. Expanding, retracting and looping endlessly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZlQF.gif)

**Simple solution**

Register a callback for every time a Transition ends, and toggle the Classes that are active. NOTE: each class should only have 1 transition.

```
    //Put this in the constructor, call once. 
    RegisterCallback<TransitionEndEvent>((e) => PlayNext());
    ToggleInClassList("$"{previousClass}");

    public void PlayNext()
    {
        // These should be "offset": One is off while the other is on. 
        ToggleInClassList("$"{previousClass}");
        ToggleInClassList($"{nextClass}");
    }
```

**Custom element solution**

A slightly more complete solution is to create a custom visual element.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

public class LoopingAnimation : VisualElement
{
        #region boilerplate

        // Required for the UI Builder
        public new class UxmlFactory : UxmlFactory<LoopingAnimation, UxmlTraits>     
        {}

        public new class UxmlTraits : VisualElement.UxmlTraits
        {
            UxmlStringAttributeDescription m_className = new UxmlStringAttributeDescription { name = "class-name", defaultValue = "animation-class" };
            UxmlIntAttributeDescription m_classCount = new UxmlIntAttributeDescription { name = "classCount", defaultValue = 1 };
            public override void Init(VisualElement ve, IUxmlAttributes bag, CreationContext cc)
            {
                base.Init(ve, bag, cc);
                var ate = ve as LoopingAnimation;
                ate.className = m_className.GetValueFromBag(bag, cc);
                ate.classCount = m_classCount.GetValueFromBag(bag, cc);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        int index = 0;

        public bool isPlaying = true;
        public string className { get; set; }
        public int classCount { get; set; }

        public VisualElement child = new VisualElement() { name =
```

"animation-target" };

```
        public LoopingAnimation() : base()
        {
            RegisterCallback<GeometryChangedEvent>(OnGeometryChangedEvent);
        }

        void OnGeometryChangedEvent(GeometryChangedEvent e)
        {
            Add(child);
            RegisterCallback<TransitionEndEvent>((e) => PlayNext());
            RegisterCallback<PointerEnterEvent>((e) => Play()); //Only here to get the ball rolling in Preview Mode
            UnregisterCallback<GeometryChangedEvent>(OnGeometryChangedEvent);
        }

        public void PlayNext()
        {
            if(!isPlaying ) return;
            Debug.Log($"Looping {index} {className}{index %classCount}");
            child.RemoveFromClassList($"{className}{index %classCount}");
            index++;
            child.AddToClassList($"{className}{index %classCount}");
        }

        public void Play()
        {
            isPlaying = true;
            style.display = DisplayStyle.Flex;
            PlayNext();
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            isPlaying = false;
            child.ClearClassList();
            style.display = DisplayStyle.None;
        }
}
```

**How to use**

In UI Builder, drag and drop this element into the scene. In the Inspector on the right, insert these values:

- The class name you want to use for animations (only supports 1 class name)
- The class count: This is the number of classes with transitions you want to use.

The class name is incremented like so:

- classname0
- classname1
- classname2

You can edit and test the animation in preview mode(!)

#### Example USS

```css
    #animation-target {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(255, 32, 32, 0.25);
        border-top-left-radius: 50%;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
        border-top-right-radius: 50%;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
    }

    .animation-0 {
        background-color: rgb(229, 107, 107);
        transition-duration: 800ms;
        transition-property: scale;
        border-left-width: 21px;
        border-right-width: 21px;
        border-top-width: 21px;
        border-bottom-width: 21px;
        scale: 2 2;
        transition-timing-function: ease-out-sine;
        border-right-color: rgb(0, 26, 255);
    }

    .animation-1 {
        background-color: rgb(229, 107, 107);
        transition-duration: 800ms;
        border-left-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
        transition-property: scale;
        border-left-width: 21px;
        border-right-width: 21px;
        border-top-width: 21px;
        border-bottom-width: 21px;
        scale: 1 1;
        transition-timing-function: ease-in-sine;
        transition-delay: 0s;
    }

    .animation-2 {
        rotate: 180deg;
        transition-property: rotate;
        transition-duration: 600ms;
        border-left-width: 21px;
        border-right-width: 21px;
        border-top-width: 21px;
        border-bottom-width: 21px;
        border-left-color: rgba(0, 22, 255, 255);
    }
```

## Known limitations:

- Only 1 transition per Class! If you add more, they will mess with the ordering or never play.
- If two subsequent animations affect the same property, and the value doesn't change, the loop ends. Unity doesn't play a transition if the previous property value matches the target transition value.